# Upload file in Retrofit 2

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

[image]

I tried the following but on response i am getting 500 error (Internal Server Error) -- help me design the interface for the request in the above screenshot...thanks

```
@Multipart
@POST("myrecord")
Call<ResponseBody> addRecord(@Query("token") String token,@Query("userid") int userId,
                             @Query("name") String name, @Part("file") RequestBody file);


File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()));
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()));` 
Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = service.addRecord(token, userId,
                "newFileName", requestFile);
        responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.d("Response", "="+response.code());
                Log.d("Response", "= "+response.message());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("failure", "message = " + t.getMessage());
                Log.d("failure", "cause = " + t.getCause());
            }
        });`
```

Comment: try removing @Multipart

Comment: @MobDev did not work bro..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following code worked :)

```
 @Multipart
@POST("myrecord")
Call<ResponseBody> addRecord(@Query("token") String token, @Query("userid") int userId,
                             @Query("name") String name, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);



 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE) && (resultCode == -1)) {

        File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()));

        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()));

        MultipartBody.Part multipartBody =MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",file.getName(),requestFile);

        Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = service.addRecord(token, userId, "fileName", multipartBody);
        responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.d("Success", "success "+response.code());
                Log.d("Success", "success "+response.message());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("failure", "message = " + t.getMessage());
                Log.d("failure", "cause = " + t.getCause());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: will you please update `getRealPathFromURI()` method ?

Comment: I am having one question that I am trying this code but now I am very much confused that how to create the asp.net web services that work properly in this above android code. I have already tried. for more please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/q/57909118/10325004 and Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

```
@Multipart
@POST("myrecord")
Call<ResponseBody> addRecord(@Part("file") RequestBody file,@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
@Query("token") String token,@Query("userid") int userId,@Query("name") String name);

RequestBody requestFile =
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

MultipartBody.Part body =
        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);


String descriptionString = "your description";

RequestBody description =
        RequestBody.create(
                MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), descriptionString);
```

for more information look into this link:
https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to send file as binary in a body without using multipart you can remove `@Multipart` annotation from your code and use `@Body` annotation. It looks like

```
@POST("myrecord")
Call<ResponseBody> addRecord(@Query("token") String token,@Query("userid") int userId,
                             @Query("name") String name, @Body RequestBody file);


File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()));
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()));
Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = service.addRecord(token, userId,
                "newFileName", requestFile);
        responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.d("Response", "="+response.code());
                Log.d("Response", "= "+response.message());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("failure", "message = " + t.getMessage());
            Log.d("failure", "cause = " + t.getCause());
        }
    });`
```

Comment: What is the difference between using this method and the Multipart one? In both cases the file will be sent as binary right?

Comment: @Mena multipart is used to send "multiple body" like multiple files or files and json, or multiple json (if you need it). if you need to send only 1 file this method is better. anyway depends on server side configuration

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Log.d("imin", "onClick: in image conversion");

    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.d("imin", "onClick: in image conversion try");

        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        Log.d("imin", "onClick: in image conversion finally");

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```