# how to execute a service correctly with @POST in java with retrofit2

Tags: java, android, web-services, retrofit2, postman

I'm using the retrofit2 library, the method I use is an @POST but I do not understand why it gives me an error, I currently send the data in an @Body however in postman I have it in the following way

[image]

so I execute it from java

```
 @POST(Constants.Retrofit.WORK_WITH_AS)
    Call<List<SuggestionsResponse>> setWorkWithAs(@Body WorkWithAs body);
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way, I need to be told what kind of note to make in order to post this data.

Comment: thats not body. you need to send those parameter in setWorkwithas

Comment: see this is how you use post api for send data

Comment: @Ashish What kind of annotation would be then?

Comment: wait i am providing you call for your api but you need some changes

Comment: @Ashish I do not understand then what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: @Ashish yes please !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186598/discussion-between-ashish-and-dbenitobaldeon).

Comment: Please check this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37049346/5180017) and [Future Studio's](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server) tutorial.